# How to to change the default file from index to a custom in React Components?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

Structure of the project generally looks like this:

```
 components
 - my-component
 - - my-component.ts
 - - index.ts
```

Where index.(ts/js) always consists of

```js
import MyComponent from './my-component';
export default MyComponent;
```

I want to remove index.(js/ts) and still import/require my components using the path

```js
import MyComponent from './components/my-component' // not having the index file!
// Please, do not suggest importing them like this
import MyComponent from './components/my-component/my-component'
```

I use Webpack 5. I know there was a [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/directory-named-webpack-plugin) for Webpack 4, but it does not work with 5.

I want NodeJS/Webpack to look for a custom filename rather than index.

Comment: index file gets ommitted in the import statement, you can rename them if you want to import them with a spesific name. What is the use case for this?

Comment: I want to have a single file components/my-component/my-component.ts, and not to have index.ts. Then I want to import those like I would import index.ts

Answer (score 0):

Some other solutions:

- You could move `components/my-component/my-component.ts` to `components/my-component.ts`.  I assume you have a reason not to do this (presumably, other files in that component directory).
- You could use [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) and list all mappings you want:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "./components/my-component": path.resolve(__dirname, 'components/my-component/my-component.js'),
      //...
    },
  },
};
```

- You could set [`resolve.mainFiles`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemainfiles) to list all of your `.js` filenames. This seems pretty ugly though, as it's a global setting.
- Are you sure that Webpack 5 doesn't support [DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/shaketbaby/directory-named-webpack-plugin)? It's [explicitly mentioned in the documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveplugins).

Comment: This is close. Moving the file too ../my-component.ts is not an option as I have css and other files.

Comment: Alias is good, but I would want each component to work like this and avoid changing webpack config for each new component. I am not completely sure that DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin does not work with 5, but on my project, I was getting something like "Can't resolve './components/my-component' in ..."

Comment: Maybe I set something wrong :(  I put that in module.exports.plugins[] and module.exports.resolve.plugins[] and still was getting the same error